# Force-directed graph visualization with buoyancy control

Tags: javascript, graph, physics-engine

I am working on a project with a force-directed graph display (specifically, I'm using [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org) with its ForceAtlas2 plugin, but can expand this to any framework). I want to know if there is an already-existing plugin or a relatively easy way to implement something like "buoyancy" of nodes in the physics system.

To put it another way: Most force-directed graph systems treat the nodes as if they are in space. This works fine for most types of data. However, some types of data, such as those clearly associated with dates and times, would be more meaningful with some kind of spatial timeline arrangement so that nodes representing earlier time periods are to the left of or above nodes representing later time periods. Rather than force all directed edges to point downwards or right (which doesn't work for all data sets), or lock one coordinate or the other (which can create arbitrary compression), is there a simple way to treat the nodes as if they are in *water*, with various degrees of "buoyancy" depending on this sort of characteristic?

Example: I have a pedigree display, and I want to visually highlight when ancestral lines converge by linking both lines to the same node. However, I still want to maintain the standard cadence of a typical pedigree chart - you go up in ancestry as you go to the right, or go up. Is there a good way to optimize a force-directed graph to do something like this?